# How to safely call Count(Func) on an IEnumerable that can be changed by another thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, linq, parallel-processing

One of my WPF element is data-bound to a property that calls `Count(Func)` on a `IEnumerable`. The property displays something like the count of active entities in the system (thus the need of a `Func` parameter).

```
public int ActiveEntitiesCount
{
    get
    {
        return Entities.Count((item) =>
        {
            //my own code, just a couple of value comparisons, very quick
        });
    }
}
```

.
However the `IEnumerable` is a list that can be changed by another thread at any time. Sometimes, the application crashes, apparently because the `IEnumerable` is modified while the `Count` function enumeration is in progress.

I can put a `try-catch` block, but how to get the value to be returned by that property?

Note: Using lock may be not practical, because I don't know all the codes that's accessing the `IEnumerable`

Comment: You could put the try/catch inside the property, and retry or return say -1 on failure. Still not a pretty solution. :(

Comment: @leppie Agree. My GUI will display "-1" and it is really weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can alleviate the issue by making a snapshot of your list before running `Count` on it. Like:

```
return Entities.ToList().Count(item => ...
```

To truly fix the issue, you would either make it thread-safe, using any of synchronization technique or to redesign it to avoid contention.

**[EDIT]** Possible solution:

```
public class MyCollection<T> : Collection<T>
{
    private readonly object syncRoot = new object();

    protected override void SetItem(int index, T item)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
            base.SetItem(index, item);
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
            base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
            base.ClearItems();
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
            base.RemoveItem(index);
    }

    public new int Count(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
            return Enumerable.Count(this, predicate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will the ToList method not throw an exception like Count()?

Comment: Like I said, it will alleviate, but not grantee to fix the issue. To truly fix the issue, you would either make it thread-safe, using any of synchronization technique or to redesign it to avoid contention.

Comment: how will it alleviate the issue?

Comment: It depends on the implementation of your `Count` and how time consuming it is. `ToList()` might be much quicker, but it depends.

Comment: Trying to improve your odds when you are playing Russian Roulette is an illusion.

Comment: @fiver - you are an angry man :). Let's say there is a database query that is executed by the func inside of Count. So the time spent on comparing every element in count is much long than the time to make a snapshot. Please show some respect to others' opinions. Moreover, I never said that this is the best solution, but in certain cases it could be.

Comment: Updated the code in the question, the code within Count only has a couple of straightforward value comparisons, should be very quick

Comment: @Alex, ah, damn, I am sorry - I overread the question - that's why it didn't make sense to me what you were saying. Sorry about that. Reverted my down vote too.

Comment: @Louis Rhys - I updated my question with possible 'true' solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I will use your idea, I hope the issue is solved (I have no idea how to test it other than running it for a long period)

Comment: @Louis Rhys - to test create multiple threads that modify the collection and call Count. Should not fail.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need *some* way of controlling the concurrency, *or* providing a snapshot, *or* using a concurrency-safe collection (like the ones in [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx)). Repeatedly trying the operation, catching the exception and retrying is likely to work, but it's pretty horrible.

Is it possible for the collection to notify this class when it changes? That way you could keep the count as a field instead of walking through it each time you need to get the property, and keep the *count* in a thread-safe way. Counting a collection within a property becomes a bit of a smell if the collection becomes large. (It's okay if it implements `IList<T>` of course, as then the call will be optimized anyway... but that's a different matter.)

If you could tell us more about the context, we may be able to help more.

Comment: It is possble to notify this class, but still the code which updates the count field will still need to count the IEnumerable, so there is still the same risk, imo

Comment: @Louis: Can it not notify the class with information about what's changed, e.g. whether values have been added or removed? How are you modifying the collection in a thread-safe way to start with? (If you "don't know all the codes accessing the IEnumerable" then it sounds like you're in a bad situation to start with IMO.)

Comment: Yes, in fact the list uses ObservableCollection, so I can know whether items have been added or removed, but iterations are still needed to know how many values are active. Is there some sort of concurrent observable collections? Can't find one in your link.

Comment: @Louis: I don't know of one, no. I hadn't spotted that you weren't just taking the count...

Comment: @Louis If you inherit the ObservableCollection, you could add the current count to the changed event. From within the collection, returning the count should be just reading an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using IEnumerable in a way that is not supported.  The source of an enumeration is not supposed to change for the lifetime that the enumeration is "open" or being used. Period.

One solution would be to require all consumers of the IEnumeration and the data source it comes from to take a mutex lock before accessing the data for any reason.  Heavy handed and noisy.

Another solution would be to maintain your own Count property which is updated (in a thread safe manner) whenever the data source changes.  This way, you don't need IEnumerable.Count().

Comment: Using InterlockedIncrement/Decrement to modify the private counter field, you don't have to take a lock to read the counter.  You could instead use a mutex lock to protect the counter updates, but then you have to take the lock when you read the counter as well.